# Cast HSSFWorkbook to Workbook

Tags: java, excel, spring-mvc

I wrote ExcelBuilder class to export data to excel file using spring mvc using org.apache.poi 3.14 but I am getting `ClassCastException`,

This is my code:

```
package net.codejava.spring;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
//import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
//import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFont;
//import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
//import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
//import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
//import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.WorkbookUtil;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.document.AbstractExcelView;

import net.codejava.spring.model.Contacting;
public class ExcelBuilder2 extends AbstractExcelView {



    @Override
    protected void buildExcelDocument(Map<String, Object> model, HSSFWorkbook workbook, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         // get data model which is passed by the Spring container
        List<Contacting> listContactings = (List<Contacting>) model.get("listContactings");
        Workbook wb = (Workbook) new HSSFWorkbook();
        CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
        // create a new Excel sheet
        Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Java Books");
        sheet.setDefaultColumnWidth((short) 30);

        // create style for header cells
        CellStyle style = (CellStyle) wb.createCellStyle();
        Font font = (Font) wb.createFont();
    //    font.setCharSet( FontCharset..getValue());
        font.setFontName("Arial");
        font.setCharSet(FontCharset.HEBREW.getValue());



     //   style.setFillForegroundColor(Color.);
        style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
       font.setBoldweight(Font.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
       // font.setColor(Color.WHITE.index);
      //  style.setFont(font);


        // create header row

        Row header = sheet.createRow(0);

        header.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue("contacting_id");
        header.getCell((short) 0).setCellStyle((CellStyle) style);

        header.createCell((short) 1).setCellValue("user_id");
        header.getCell((short) 1).setCellStyle((CellStyle) style);

        header.createCell((short) 2).setCellValue("subject");
        header.getCell((short) 2).setCellStyle((CellStyle)style);

        header.createCell((short) 3).setCellValue("location");
        header.getCell((short) 3).setCellStyle((CellStyle)style);

        header.createCell((short)4).setCellValue("content");
        header.getCell((short)4).setCellStyle((CellStyle)style);

        header.createCell((short)5).setCellValue("department");
        header.getCell((short)5).setCellStyle((CellStyle)style);



        header.createCell((short)6).setCellValue("status");
        header.getCell((short)6).setCellStyle((CellStyle)style);




        header.createCell((short)7).setCellValue("contacting_date");
        header.getCell((short)7).setCellStyle((CellStyle)style);


        header.createCell((short)8).setCellValue("house_Number");
        header.getCell((short)8).setCellStyle((CellStyle)style);

        header.createCell((short)9).setCellValue("Urgency");
        header.getCell((short)9).setCellStyle((CellStyle)style);

        header.createCell((short)10).setCellValue("is_inspector");
        header.getCell((short)10).setCellStyle((CellStyle)style);

        header.createCell((short)11).setCellValue("inspectorStatus");
        header.getCell((short)11).setCellStyle((CellStyle)style);



        header.createCell((short)12).setCellValue("stringDate");
        header.getCell((short)12).setCellStyle((CellStyle)style);

        header.createCell((short)13).setCellValue("openedBy");
        header.getCell((short)13).setCellStyle((CellStyle)style);

        // create data rows
        int rowCount = 1;

        for (Contacting Contacting : listContactings) {
            Row aRow = sheet.createRow(rowCount++);
            if(Contacting.getContacting_id()!=null)
            aRow.createCell((short) 0).setCellValue(Contacting.getContacting_id());
            if(Contacting.getUser_id()!=null)
            aRow.createCell((short)1).setCellValue(Contacting.getUser_id());
            if(Contacting.getSubject()!=null)
            aRow.createCell((short)2).setCellValue(Contacting.getSubject());
            if(Contacting.getLocation()!=null)
            aRow.createCell((short)3).setCellValue(Contacting.getLocation());
            if(Contacting.getContent()!=null)
            aRow.createCell((short)4).setCellValue(Contacting.getContent());
            if(Contacting.getdepartment()!=null)
            aRow.createCell((short)5).setCellValue(Contacting.getdepartment());
            if(Contacting.getStatus()!=null)
            aRow.createCell((short)6).setCellValue(Contacting.getStatus());
            if(Contacting.getContacting_date()!=null)
            aRow.createCell((short)7).setCellValue(Contacting.getContacting_date());
            if(Contacting.getHouse_Number()!=null)
            aRow.createCell((short)8).setCellValue(Contacting.getHouse_Number());
            if(Contacting.getUrgency()!=null)
            aRow.createCell((short)9).setCellValue(Contacting.getUrgency());
            if(Contacting.getIs_inspector()!=null)
            aRow.createCell((short)10).setCellValue(Contacting.getIs_inspector());
            if(Contacting.getInspectorStatus()!=null)
            aRow.createCell((short)11).setCellValue(Contacting.getInspectorStatus());
            if(Contacting.getStringDate()!=null)
            aRow.createCell((short)12).setCellValue(Contacting.getStringDate());
            if(Contacting.getOpenedBy()!=null)
            aRow.createCell((short)13).setCellValue(Contacting.getOpenedBy());



        }
    }


}
```

But i get this **exception**:

**`HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook cannot be cast to org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook`**

How to solve this exception?

Comment: HSSFWorkbook already implements Workbook, so there is no need to cast it. Just use `Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook()`

Comment: Also, `XSSFWorkbook` would be a better choice.

Comment: it doesnt work! ask me to add cast to work book and XSSFWorkbook cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html according to documentation, HSSFWorkbook does implement Workbook. Provide more information in your question - for example, where do you import the Workbook class?

Comment: i use org.apache.poi 3.14 dependency

Comment: I think there are 2 different `Workbook` interfaces/classes, try to remove the `import` for it, and see what suggestions you get from your IDE.

Comment: Just to confirm, from which line are you getting that exception?

Comment: i use that  imports import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

Comment: Workbook wb = (Workbook) new HSSFWorkbook();